# Maven node skipping Spring Boot deployment artefact on Jelastic

Tags: jelastic

I'm using the new Jelastic Spring Boot node which seems to work great if you upload a packaged Spring Boot jar.

However using the Maven build nodes to build and deploy from Github directly just gives the following;

```
[INFO] --- jelastic-maven-plugin:1.8:deploy (default-cli) @ <app> ---
[INFO] Skiping deploy artifact. Artifact packaging not WAR or EAR
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.514 s
```

The [documentation](http://blog.jelastic.com/2017/04/27/hosting-spring-boot-java-applications/) indicates this should work, any ideas where I might be going wrong?

I do notice that the jelastic-maven-plugin being used is 1.8 while in the maven repo there is a version 1.8.1 released more recently. Might this remove the offending [WAR check](https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.jelastic/jelastic-maven-plugin?className=com.jelastic.DeployMojo&source)? In which case this would be an issue with my Jelastic provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, the was a bug in maven plugin version 1.8, it is already fixed in version 1.8.1, but it looks like the configuration that is globally set in a platform that you are using is configured to use older version of maven plugin, if you let us know the hosting service provider name where you faced with this issue - we will help to resolve this problem very quickly. 
Thank you for reporting this.

Comment: Layershift is the provider, I've raised this with them and they mentioned they will be updating the platform accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Nick, the problem should be fixed now. Could you please try again? Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!